# Image Classification toolbar disabled in ArcMap 10.1

Tags: arcmap

I'm trying to select an image from Image Classification toolbar but the dropdown arrow box is disabled. The 'Classification' dropdown box and all of its contents are also disabled.

Any help would be great.

Comment: What format is the image (.img, .tif, etc)?

Comment: It's working now. I've added Spatial Analyst extension and the toolbar is enabled.

Comment: @Aaron The image is in '.img' format. I was starting to wonder if that was the cause.

Comment: Then please mark your question as solved and provide the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Image Classification toolbar needs Spatial Analyst Extension license. Please check the extension is available.
[Customize] > [Extensions] > [Spatial Analyst]